# Laravel changing config value of view_id in Analytics.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My config/analytics.php

```
<?php 

return [

'view_id' => 1111111,


'cache_lifetime_in_minutes' => 60 * 24,


'cache' => [
    'store' => 'file',
  ],
];
```

What I want to happen is set the `view_id` `=>` `googleApi` at my Controller.

```
public function showSpecificSite($site_id){

$reports = Report::whereHas('site', function($query) use($site_id) {
         $query->where('site_id', $site_id);
})->get(['email_date', 'url', 'recipient', 'report_id', 'site_id']);

$googleApi = DB::table('sites')->where('site_id', $site_id)->value('ga_id');
Config::set('view_id', $googleApi);

$siteName = Site::find($site_id)->site_name;

return view('newsite', compact('site_id', 'siteName', 'reports'));
}
```

My query

```
public function showMonthlyReport($site_id, $report_id)
{

$analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(Period::days(30),
    'ga:',
    [
        'metrics' => 'ga:users,ga:newUsers,ga:sessions,ga:sessionsPerUser,ga:pageviews,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:bounceRate',
        'start-date' => '2018-08-01',
        'end-date' => '2018-08-30',
    ]);

}
```

I tried `config:set` but it didn't help me at all.

Do you have any idea or thoughts how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
Config::set('analytics.view_id', $googleApi);
```

At the beginning, you should always put your config name (without `.php` extension)

Comment: how about the analytics.php what should I put here. `'view_id' => ?`

Comment: it was built in on my laravel app all my config files have `.php`

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin That's why all config keys have format `{configFileNameWithoutExtension}.{keyFromFile}`. Otherwise if you had configs `foo` and `bar` and in each of them you would have `id`, then it would be a problem. And in such case you should just use `foo.id` and `bar.id`

Comment: I still got.  `There was no view id specified. You must provide a valid view id to execute querys on Google Analytics.`

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin But you didn't show how you use this what you put into config, so it's hard to say how are you using it later.

Comment: my config/analytics is currently `'view_id' => ,`

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin Yes, I understand it, but you told something about query. In which query you use `config('analytics.view_id')`? There is no such code in code you provided in your question

Comment: I edited my content already. That's why in the showSpecificSite need to set my analytics view id so that when I use the query in my report It can automatically detect that view_id = googleApi

Comment: Well, but in this query you don't use anywhere this config. If it's used by 3rd party library you might need to analyze its code

Comment: that's weird. I thought when I set it at specificSite it should be fine already at the monthlyReport function but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `config()` helper:

```
config(['analytics.view_id' => $googleApi]);
```

Source: [Laravel Accessing Configuration Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

Comment: What should I put on my config/analytics.php?